# how to download the file that uploading

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I am developing an upload feature from excel files, after I parse the uploading excel file and modify some values in Workbook, how to download the Workbook? below as my upload interface:

```
public void batchImport(HttpServletResponse response, MultipartFile file) {
    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    boolean isExcel2003 = true;
    if (fileName.matches("^.+\\.(?i)(xlsx)$")) {
      isExcel2003 = false;
    }
    InputStream is = file.getInputStream();
    if (isExcel2003) {
      Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(is);
    } else {
      Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(is);
    }
    // some logic to handle wb

    // download an excel by the Workbook
    response.setHeader("content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader(
        "Content-Disposition",
        "attachment;filename="
            + URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "utf-8").replaceAll("\\+", "%20").replaceAll("_", "\\/"));
    wb.write(response.getOutputStream()); 
}
```

I debug it at download line, the wb value is right, no errors but download nothing. how could I modify it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" gives zero information.

Comment: no errors, but download nothing

Comment: `OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); wb.write(out); out.flush(); wb.close();`?

Comment: tried it, doesn't work

Comment: please show your spring controller method

Comment: @PostMapping(value = Mappings.UPLOAD)
  @ResponseBody
  public void upload(
          MultipartFile file,
          HttpServletResponse response)
          throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, IOException {
    
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
      return;
    }
   
    productService.batchImport( file, response);

Comment: `.replaceAll("_", "\\/")` I do not understand its intent. An underscore seems fine in the filename, the backslash is unneeded, and slash is a directory separator. Maybe `.replaceAll("[/\\\\]", "_")`?

Comment: ok, but I think it won't affect download, you can ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostMapping(value = Mappings.UPLOAD)
@ResponseBody
public void upload( MultipartFile file, HttpServletResponse response)
```

A void method has no return type, so there's no response body. You need to specify return type e.g. ResponseEntity and return a value.

Or remove ResponseBody annotation.

Look here for samples: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-image-media-data

Comment: really? I searched for downloading method by spring boot and found return type is always void, seems it doesn't matter, HttpServletResponse will write the Bytestream

Comment: if you want to use the low level way then remove ResponseBody annotation